# Aurelia.io for hybrid apps

Tags: javascript, hybrid-mobile-app, aurelia

I'd like to ask whether the Aurelia JS framework can be used as replacement for i.e. Ionic in hybrid app development. I have seen some tries, how to integrate with Cordova, but from their pages it is not really clear how it should be done.

Comment: Cordova embeds a browser that can run JavaScript, Aurelia is a JavaScript framework. What special integration do you expect?

Comment: Add least some blueprint how to do it. They are saying it can be used for mobile dev, but I have found no article abou it. From [this](https://medium.com/@jetstreamin/running-aurelia-on-cordova-350f8f5d15fc) I am none the wiser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just use Aurelia on Cordova as you would in a regular browser. That's basically what your linked article tries to tell. Get started with Aurelia and host it in Cordova. But this does not solve what you might expect as a replacement for Ionic. Basically you would have to build this layer of abstraction yourself or use another UI framework that suits your needs.

@EisenbergEffect talked in comments about the "secret" project named Aurelia Interface that will probably be the replacement (Aurelia + Cordova) for Ionic (Angular + Cordova). But currently not too much is available in the wild about this.

http://blog.durandal.io/2015/09/05/aurelia-early-september-release-notes/#comment-2242530528

https://twitter.com/eisenbergeffect/status/627163846709526529

Comment: There's some new info on Aurelia Interface on their blog at http://blog.durandal.io/2015/11/20/aurelia-beta-week-day-5-aurelia-interface/

Comment: Latest news about this! http://eisenbergeffect.bluespire.com/aurelia-interface-update/

Comment: As of 4 Nov 2016, Aurelia Interface is no more. It will be replaced by Aurelia UX, see: http://blog.aurelia.io/2016/11/04/introducing-aurelia-ux/

Answer (score 4):

There is also [Framework7](https://framework7.io/) (https://framework7.io/) which is agnostic to which JS framework you use. You can find a small example here: http://www.jujens.eu/posts/en/2016/Mar/15/ionic2-aurelia-f7/ which also compares what would be like writing the same app with Ionic2 vs Aurelia + Framework7.
I hope it helps.